# ASP Classic inline code + jQuery: How to do ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, vbscript, asp-classic

I've working on a large asp classic site and trying to introduce couple of new vbscript function that will be triggered from jQuery based on some event, after which jQuery will do a partial update of the page.

My question is: If all the code (ASP classic vbscript function + html and jquery) are all in the same file (there are many vbscript functions in this page), how can i make a ajax call to a function in this page, get it to be processed on server and respond back.

So for example:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            .....
                <%
                    Function  checkUsername( ....)
                        ....
                    end function

                    Function  checkCredentials( .... )
                      .....
                    end function
                %> 
            <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $( "#username" ).blur(function() {
                    var username = $('#username_field").val();
                    checkUsername(username);
                });

                function checkUsername(usr) //the function that loads pages via AJAX            
                {
                    $.ajax({    
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "WHAT TO PUT HERE?????",
                        data: usr,
                        cache: false,   
                        success: function(msg){
                            ....
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            ....
            Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username">
                            .....
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't directly call a VBScript function from jQuery/JavaScript/AJAX per se, but you could just pass a URL variable that triggers your ASP code to run a specific VBScript function and then stop.

I'm not too familiar with the jQuery ajax function, but if you specified something like the following:

```
.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '<%= Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME") %>?u=' + usr,
    ...
});
```

It should call your page again with the username passed as the `u` query string variable. Then, somewhere near the start of your ASP code, you'd want to do something like this:

```
<%
    Dim strUser
    strUser = Request.QueryString("u")

    If Len(strUser) > 0 Then

        ' Write an ajax response based on this user...
        Response.Write ...

        ' Stop processing...
        Response.End

    End If
%>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The answer to his question is, you can't. VBScript is executed when the page is rendered and the jQuery is executed on document load. It's fundamentally impossible to do what he's ask.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the basic idea, modify to meet your requirements.

Create a seperate page with just the code you want to execute like, getCustomers.asp:

```
<%
response.ContentType="text/HTML"
response.Charset="ISO-8859-1"

on error resume next
set conn=Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
conn.Provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
conn.Open("C:/WebData/Northwind.mdb")
set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.recordset")
sql="SELECT CompanyName,City,Country FROM Customers"

rs.Open sql, conn
if err <> 0 then
  response.write(err.description)
  set rs=nothing
  set conn=nothing
else
  response.write("<table border='1'>")
  response.write("<tr><th>Name</th><th>City</th><th>Country</th></tr>")
  do until rs.EOF
    response.write("<tr>")
    for each x in rs.Fields
      response.write("<td>" & x.value & "</td>")
    next
    response.write("</tr>")
    rs.MoveNext
  loop
  response.write("</table>")
  rs.close
  conn.close
end if
on error goto 0
%>
```

If you are only doing a get then your jquery call could do this:

```
$.get("getCustomers.asp", function(data){
  alert("Result: " + data);
});
```